# Datatables hide columns if user doesn't have the rigth role in Spring security

Tags: javascript, html, spring-security, datatables

I have to hide some columns of my [datatable](http://www.datatables.net/) if the user isn't ADMIN.
In HTML I have this code

```
<table id="fleetsTable"
    class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Application</th>
            <th>Cubic</th>
            <th>Power</th>
            <th>Euro class</th>
            <th>Engine Type</th>
            <th>Traction</th>
            <th>Transmission</th>
            <th>Cars</th>
            <th sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The table is filled with ajax value through javascript. I have this code:

```
if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#fleetsTable' ) ) {
    fleetTable = $('#fleetsTable').DataTable({
        responsive: true,
        //disable order and search on column
        columnDefs: [
             {
                 targets: [7, 8],
                 orderable: false,
                 searchable: false,
             }
         ],
         //fix problem with responsive table
         "autoWidth": false,
         "ajax": "fleet/table",
         "columns": [
             { "data": "application" },
             { "data": "cubic" },
             { "data": "power" },
             { "data": "euroClass" },
             { "data": "engineType" },
             { "data": "traction" },
             { "data": "transmission" },

             { 
                 data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                 return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="showCarsButton">Show cars</button>'; 
                 }

             },
             {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                 return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteFleet" data-toggle="modal"'
                 +'data-target="#deleteFleetModal">Delete</button>' 
             }
             }
        ],
    });
}
else {
    fleetTable.ajax.url("table").load();
}
```

To check if user has the right role I use a hidden input in my HTML and

```
document.getElementById("role").value=="[ROLE_ADMIN]"
```

in javascript.
But how can I avoid to build the delete button? The html code only hide the name of the column. Thanks

UPDATE: for now I hide the column

```
if (!(document.getElementById("role").value=="[ROLE_ADMIN]")){
        // Get the column API object
        var column = fleetTable.column(8);
        // Toggle the visibility
        column.visible( false);
}
```

but I prefer to don't create the column

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Very simple. You can use `columnDef`'s `visible` property :

```js
columnDefs : [
  { targets: 8, visible: document.getElementById('role').value == '[ROLE_ADMIN]' }
]
```

...Assuming it is column #8 we want to skip - by that the column is *never* created if `#role` is any different from `[ROLE_ADMIN]`.

Comment: yes, you had right. I hadn't thought of this use. I have only fix an error in your response. Thanks

Comment: Is this a secure way, coz we are having printed ROLE in html source. Users can see the role names in view source ??

Comment: @prashanth-gm Have you tried? Setting a column  `visible: false` *completely* removes the column from DOM, and as above before the table is even populated. But if secret data is your concern you should never ever try to control visibility clientside, users always have the ability to check out for example AJAX responses in their browsers network tab, they can sniff on network data etc.  But that was not the issue above, the question is about hiding columns for certain user roles.

Comment: This is very insecure.

Comment: @JelleBlaauw, Yes indeed. If OP wanted *security* the column should be created / not created serverside.  At least the column is not just hidden, it is never created. An attack should set `#role` before the dataTable is instantiated....

Answer (score 1):

Although , i am late to the party, but i want to share my solution as well.

In Javascript (Used with Laravel)

```
var role = "{{ Auth::user()->role_id }} ";

$(function(){
    var showAdminColumns =  role ==3 ? true:false;

    $('#datatable').DataTable({
        serverSide:true,
        processing:true,
        pageLength:25,
        ajax:urlMasterData,
        columns:[

            { data:'edit' , name: 'edit' ,visible : showAdminColumns},
            { data:'cancel' , name: 'cancel' ,visible : showAdminColumns},

        ],

    })
})
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the column array as a local variable. Push the required columns first and then depending on the condition you can push the delete column. Then assign this array to columns.Like

```
var cols= [
             { "data": "application" },
             { "data": "cubic" },
             { "data": "power" },
             { "data": "euroClass" },
             { "data": "engineType" },
             { "data": "traction" },
             { "data": "transmission" },

             { 
                 data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                 return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="showCarsButton">Show cars</button>'; 
                 }

             },
          ];
     if (!(document.getElementById("role").value=="[ROLE_ADMIN]")){
          cols.push( {data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
             return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="deleteFleet" data-toggle="modal"'
             +'data-target="#deleteFleetModal">Delete</button>' 
         }
        };
```

and then initialize the table like

```
 "columns": cols
```

Answer (score 0):

it is work for me just checking condition true or false on $permission.

In Javascript with Laravel

```
var permission = "{{$permission}}";
$(function() {
var showhideColumns =  permission;
  console.log(showhideColumns);
    $('#tbl-order-items').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    pageLength: 50,
    ajax: "{{ url('/supplier_order/processing_data_order_item_history', 
       ['supplier_order_id'=>$supplier_order_id]) }}",
        columns: [
                  { data: 'image', name: 'image' },
                  { data: 'sku', name: 'sku' },
                  { data: 'product_name', name: 'product_name' },
                  { data: 'status', name: 'status' },
                  { data: 'option', name: 'option' },
                  { data: 'qty', name: 'qty' },
                  { data: 'price', name: 'price' },
                  { data: 'supplier_price', name: 'supplier_price' },
                  { data: 'supplier_actual_price_yuan', name: 
                  'supplier_actual_price_yuan' },
                  { data: 'supplier_actual_price_usd', name: 
                  'supplier_actual_price_usd', visible : showhideColumns  },
                  { data: 'arrived_date', name: 'arrived_date'},
                  { data: 'actions', name: 'actions'}
              ],
              "language": {processing: '<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-2x 
              fa-fw" style="color:blue"></i><span class="sr-only">Data is 
               Loading...</span> '},

            });

          });
```