# Hide Datatables ActionButton Edit and Delete based on UserRole

Tags: c#, html, jquery, css, datatable

**Objective**: Hide buttons for action `Delete` and `Edit` based on UserRole

[image]

Did some research and attempted a couple of solutions but unfortunately doesn't get the desired result.

```
@model IEnumerable<VmSTicketing.Models.Ticket>
@using VmSTicketing.Utility;

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/AdminLTE/_Layout.cshtml";
    var RoleCheck = (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Manager) ? "true" : "false");
}

<br />

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <h2 class="text-primary">Lista tiketa</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 text-right">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" asp-action="Upsert"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i> &nbsp; Novi tiket</a>
    </div>
</div>

<br />

<div class="p-4 border rounded">
    <table id="tblData" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr class="table-info">
                <th>Opis</th>
                <th>Datum i vrijeme slanja</th>
                <th>Vrsta Tiketa</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                @*<th>Datum i vrijeme zavrsetka</th>*@
                <th>Korisnik</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>   
    </table>
</div>


<partial name="UserDetails" />


@section Scripts{
    <script src="~/js/ticket.js"></script>
}
```

Here is my JavaScript and calling DataTable

```
var dataTable;


$(document).ready(function () {
    loadDataTable();
});


function loadDataTable() {
    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({

        "ajax": {
            "url": "/Manager/Ticket/GetAll"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "description", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "dateAndTime", "width": "15%" },
            { "data": "ticketType.name", "width": "10%" },
            { "data": "status", "width": "10%" },
            {
                "data": "applicationUser.name",
                "width": "10%",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return '<a id="' + data + '" class="text-info user-details" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userDetails" href="' + data + '" target_blank>' + data + '</a>'
                }
            },
            {
                "data": "id",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return `
                            <div class="text-center">   
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Details/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                   <i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i>
                                </a>   
                                <a href="/Manager/Ticket/Upsert/${data}" class="btn btn-success text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-edit"></i> 
                                </a>
                                <a onclick=Delete("/Manager/Ticket/Delete/${data}") class="btn btn-danger text-white" style="cursor:pointer">
                                    <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i> 
                                </a>                              
                            </div>
                           `;
                }, "width": "15%"
            }
        ]
    });
}



$("#tblData").on("click", "a.user-details", function () {
    var name = $(this).attr('id');
    $.get("/Manager/Ticket/GetByName?name=" + name, function (result) {        
        $('#ImePrezime').val(result.data[0].name);
        $('#Email').val(result.data[0].email);
        $('#BrTel').val(result.data[0].phoneNumber);
        $("#userDetails").modal({ show: true })
    });
});



function Delete(url) {
    swal({
        title: "Da li ste sigurni da zelite izbrisati tiket?",
        text: "Necete moci vratiti podatke!",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: true,
        dangerMode: true
    }).then((willDelete) => {
        if (willDelete) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "DELETE",
                url: url,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        toastr.success(data.message);
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr.error(data.message);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**REFERENCE**

[Hide buttons when no result on filtering](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/47843/i-need-to-hide-the-excel-pdf-print-buttons-and-searchbox-on-datatable-when-no-result-on-filtering)

[Role based column visibility](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/10991/role-based-column-visibility)

Comment: Set visible = false.  See: https://way2java.com/awt-components/java-making-button-invisible/

Comment: I set visibile = false but once I set it buttons are hidden also for Admin Role

Comment: The use code similar to the variable RoleCheck to make button visible or invisible.

Comment: Yes, I used alredy and it thow me error message. I used something like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458388/datatables-hide-columns-if-user-doesnt-have-the-rigth-role-in-spring-security
I declare var RoleCheck:@(User.IsInRole("Admin"): "true" ? "false");

Comment: Does the server webpage have an element for ROLE?  Do you have a class object for SD.Role_Manager?

Comment: yes, I have object class

Comment: Make sure the class object is working.

Comment: yes, it is working. I have alredy test

Comment: You need to isolate error better so I can help.  It looks like code is correct, but can't duplicate error.  Need your help.

Comment: Yes, tell me what do you need. I am here for any misunderstanding

Comment: Does RoleCheck get correct value? var RoleCheck = (User.IsInRole(SD.Role_Manager) ? "true" : "false");  What code are you using to make buttons invisible.

Comment: @jdweng No, it is not execute, It throw error 
`Uncaught ReferenceError: User is not defined` 
I using 
`"columnDefs": [
            { "visible": RoleCheck, "targets": 5 }
        ],`

Comment: `"columnDefs": [
            { "visible": false, "targets": 5 }
        ],` 
Something like this work, but I have tree button and I want to hide two of them

Comment: The link you provided is getting the values from a table.  You do not have a table.  Instead you have the variable SD.Role_Manager.  You do not need the table.  Just bypass the table and get status from the variable SD.Role_Manager

Comment: How to do this ? I am not sure what do you mean ? Can you explain in my code example

Comment: You should probably do this server side, nothing to do with Javascript/client side as a user could get round anything like a button being hidden.

Comment: I have alredy try but doesnt go well !